# Java - BufferedImage (ImageIO.Read) OutOfMemory Heap Space

Tags: java, out-of-memory, bufferedimage, heap-memory, javax.imageio

Ok, so I am getting an Out of Memory (Heap Space) error in my code, and I have figured out (with profiling) that the error is coming from the creation of images.

What I have is a class that creates an image into a smaller one, and then that class will be painted.

The problem is that if I want to load up 1000+ of these images into JPanels, I get to around 750 before it taps out, and I don't really want to extend the memory of java.

Heres the code:

```
class Foo extends JPanel{
private BufferedImage image;
private Image scaled;   
public Foo(String link){
    try{
        setPreferredSize(new Dimension(50,50));
        image = ImageIO.read(new URL(link)); //Cause for memory leak
        scaled= image.getScaledInstance(100, 140, BufferedImage.SCALE_FAST);
        image.flush();
                    //tried image = null; but did not help memory
    }
    catch(Exception e){}
}

public void paintComponent(Graphics g){
    super.paintComponent(g);
    g.drawImage(scaled, 5, 5, null);
}
}
```

So basically, is there a more efficient way to read a link into an image, or some how remove unnecessary memory?

Comment: Are you showing 1000 images at once?

Comment: Yeah... I understand that will take a lot of memory, but there still needs to be a way to read them with less memory.

Comment: Why not read in a bunch of images when needed, and release them when not needed?

Comment: Well, I was just trying to make a sort of image library, so it can store x amount of images and then load them into a scroll pane, so when you scroll down you see all the images.

Comment: Never leave an empty catch block. At the least, have `e.printStackTrace()`. If you know an exception is never supposed to happen, leave a comment in the catch block saying why that exception will never be thrown, but still print the stack trace. If something goes horribly wrong, it's better to know about it than not.

Comment: Well, if you're using Microsoft Word to edit a huge text file with images, you can bet that it doesn't load the whole file in all at once, but rather loads what you need, and then loads more if you need more.

Comment: Is there a way to detect when you scroll down to load more of an array list?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not sure if this will be enough, but you can eliminate the use of `scaled` with the use of the following method:

```
drawImage(Image img, int x, int y, int width, int height, ImageObserver observer)
```

Comment: What would the imageObserver be?

Comment: I didn't get a heap space error this time, but now I got a GC overhead limit exceeded. *edit* And then I got heap space shortly after that.

Answer (score 0):

Know problem...

You probably don't need to re-read the full images each time.

I have implemented a similar feature.
What I do is that I store snapshots of every image at a desired size +  I include in the filename the timestamp of this snapshot so that I know if the snapshot is still up-to-date.

This does not solve your problem for the initial snapshot making but well for later uses.